# Problem running React app in Nginx Docker container

Tags: reactjs, nginx

I bundle my react app using the `npm run-script build`, then copy the build output files into the Nginx docker image along with the `nginx.config` file. When I run the created Docker image, the css and images does not load properly in the first time - because of this UI components are rendered misaligned. However, if I navigate back to the home page from other pages all the components loads properly (the css, images and other material ui components, alignments). I see this is something related to static resources loading from the the relative path, but couldn't figure out a fix.

My React app configuration

- I have set `homepage` in `package.json` - `homepage: "/home/"`.
- Also have tried to set `PUBLIC_URL` variable in the `.env` file
- Nginx.conf

  ```
  server {

      listen 8080 default_server;

      root /var/www;
      index index.html index.htm;      

      location ~* \.(?:manifest|appcache|html?|xml|json)$ {
        expires -1;
      }

      location ~* \.(?:css|js)$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        expires 1y;
        access_log off;
        add_header Cache-Control "public";
      }

      location ~ ^.+\..+$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
      }

      location /home/ {
          try_files $uri $uri/ /home/index.html;
      }
  }
  ```

Did I miss anything?